# RDP from Ubuntu to Windows Server 2012 from WAN

Tags: remmina

I'm having a problem when trying to connect to our RDP server from outside the LAN.

I have a `.rdp` file and I have imported it to Remmina 1.2.31.3 . Everything works fine when I'm connecting to the server from LAN, but if I try to connect from WAN, I get this error message

```
Connection to RDP server x.x.x.x failed
```

I have tried to change security types to "RDP,NLA,TLS,Negotiate", none of them worked.

If I write `telnet "servername.domain" 3389`, it says "Connected"

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a Windows related issue, not a Remmina related issue.  Especially since I know that NAT'd RDP doesn't like to behave when Windows is the receiver of that connection. Perhaps you should reask this over on [Super User](https://superuser.com), since it's likely the RDP server at fault?

Comment: i don't think that it's a RDP server fault because other users from Windows or MAC systems can connect without problems (from WAN)